# resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri

Tags: android, bitmap

Can someone help me? I have an error, but I do not know why:

> W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
>
> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)

Here is my code:

```
public void chargement() {
    listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("titre", list.get(i).getTitre());
        map.put("url", list.get(i).getUrl());
        map.put("img", String.valueOf(getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i).getUrl(), "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
        if (list.get(i).getEtoile1().equals("true")) {
            map.put("et1", String.valueOf(R.drawable.etoile));
        }
        if (list.get(i).getEtoile2().equals("true")) {
            map.put("et2", String.valueOf(R.drawable.etoile));
        }
        if (list.get(i).getEtoile3().equals("true")) {
            map.put("et3", String.valueOf(R.drawable.etoile));
        }

        map.put("categorie", list.get(i).getNomCategorie());

        listItem.add(map);
    }


    mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.categorie,
            new String[]{"img", "titre", "et1", "et2", "et3"}, new int[]{R.id.img, R.id.titre, R.id.etoile1, R.id.etoile2, R.id.etoile3});

    maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);
}
```